# Connecting separate Airlines in Thailand

Tags: customs-and-immigration, thailand, bangladeshi-citizens

Do I need a transit visa in Don Mueang Airport (DMK) of Thailand  during traveling to Tokyo from Dhaka, Bangladesh?
Because, I am going to travel by two separate Airlines; Dhaka-Bangkok by Thai Lion Airways and Bangkok-Tokyo by Air Asia.
I will return in the same way.

There is 6:30 hours of layover on the way of Tokyo and 3:30 hour of layover on the way of Dhaka. I have no check in luggage.
If no visa requires, then: How I can manage Boarding pass of Air Asia in Bangkok without crossing immigration?

I am from Bangladesh.

Comment: Is this is single ticket ?

Comment: No, this is separate tickets.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that you will need a transit visa. According to https://www.don-mueang-airport.com/terminal-2.php Air Asia flies from Terminal 1 and Thai Lion flies from Terminal 2. I don't think there is an airside connection between the terminals.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But according to your link,  both air lines, Air asia and Thai lion air are operated from terminal 2.

Comment: Might be both. See https://www.don-mueang-airport.com/terminal-1.php which lists Thai Air Asia X and Air Asia Berhard in Terminal 1.

Comment: In that case, should I take multi entry tranvel visa or transit visa?